# React native doesn't start metro bundler on chrome after i try to run npm start on terminal

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

[metro bundler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydqko.jpg)
I'm trying to run an app published by other programmer but it doesn't run metro bundler on google chrome when I type npm start on terminal.

On the other hand, I created a project and run it and it works
[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFmaj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependencies of the other developer's project by running 'npm install' before starting metro bundler.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work :( 

"warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app..."

Comment: Have you tried running it on a mobile device with the Expo Go app? Normally when I received that error on my phone it had to do with not being on the same network

Answer (score 0):

Open new terminal and run below command, It will bring up expo dev client.

```
expo start --dev-client
```

[image]

---

Sometimes it might throw an error as below.

> Missing package "metro/src/lib/attachWebsocketServer" in the project. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.

To fixing this issue, run the command

```
npm install -g expo-cli
npm install expo-dev-client
expo start --dev-client
```