# Expo developer Tool is not launching at browser

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I eject my project because I used Expokit and now I updated **Expo SDK to 42 and EXPO CLI** with the latest version, But now am trying to run the developer tool with **expo start** but it runs only terminal, not able to launch in the browser. I tried to enable and disable with shift+D but no use.

> % expo start
> Starting project at /Volumes/D/SourceCode/Expo_upgrade
> Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
> Starting Metro Bundler
> Your native app is running at exp://192.168.1.12:19000
> Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.

Comment: I am experiencing this now, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Update July 25, 2022: expo-cli@6.0.0 has been released with the web UI removed. The last release to include the web UI is expo-cli@5.5.1

https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Answer (score 0):

Open new terminal and run below command, It will bring up expo dev client.

```
expo start --dev-client
```

For more info, view this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72402241/11844048