# Metro Bundler on Browser is not displayed

Tags: react-native, npm, metro-bundler

Im new on react native. npm start is starting the Metro Bundler on Terminal but no on the Browser.by "w" cmd Metro Bundler **THE MENU ON THE LEFT** is NOT displayed on Browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72402241/11844048

Comment: @andrewcomplainer have you figured this out? I got the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

That feature is deprecated and in the new version of expo is no longer available.

more info: https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you would like to open the additional debug tools that are available with React Native.

In the terminal that is spawned by the Metro bundler you can enter the **"d"** key and it should open the developer menu for both the iOS and Android device that you have connected. In the developer menu you can then launch additional debug tools like Flipper by choosing **"Open Debugger"** or React DevTools in Chrome by choosing **"Open React DevTools"**.

If that doesn't work, what usually works for me is entering the key combination - **⌘ + D [On Mac for iOS]** or **⌘ + M [On Mac for Android]** | **Ctrl + M [On Windows for Android]**. This will also open the developer menu on the device or emulator/simulator that you have connected to Metro.

**NOTE** - You tagged **microsoft-metro** when it should've been **metro-bundler**

**Additional Resources:**

- [React-Native Debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#:%7E:text=You%20can%20access%20the%20developer,M%20on%20Windows%20and%20Linux.)
- [Metro Docs](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/concepts)

**What you should expect:**

[image: developer-menu-ios]

Comment: No not the debug tools. I mean the menu on the left when u give npm start - > w (open with web browser) -> and now the menu on the left "Run on android device emulator, Run in webbrowser, Send link with email, Publish or republich project..